# How to wait until a specific line is printed to os.Stderr?

Tags: go

I'm running a Goroutine which, after some delay, logs a specific line to `os.Stderr`. I'd like to wait until that line is logged. So far, what I've tried is

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        log.Println("Hello, world!")
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stderr)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "Hello, world!") {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I run this, it just blocks:

```
> go run main.go
2022/04/17 00:31:43 Hello, world!
```

Should this scanner not capture the standard error output and hit the `break` statement?

Comment: `os.Stderr` is an `io.Writer` & you are trying to use it as an `io.Reader`. You'll need to set your log output to, say a pipe or   an `io.TeeReader` to be able to scan for certain output.

Comment: @colm.anseo I don't think your assertion that `os.Stderr` is not an `io.Reader` is correct: if it didn't satisfy the `io.Reader` interface, the code would not even compile. Here is its implementation of the `Read` method: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ebe77a2fda1ee9ff6fd9a3e08933ad1ebaea039/src/os/file.go#L115.

Comment: The code compiles - so yes it is a file descriptor that handles the `io.Reader` interface. But the output is read by the shell or the next piped program by default. If you want to read/scan what's written, you need to put the hooks in place *before* you start logging.

Comment: I believe it might be a code smell to rely on such a mechanism. Much better to use proper concurrency primitives. In this case, one way is to pass a channel to the goroutine, have the goroutine close the channel, and have the main function read from the channel until it's closed.

Comment: @Thomas maybe - but if the log event is coming from an external package that one cannot control - it may be the only option. The OP may need to clarify the larger goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to intercept output, you can use a pipe, like so:

```
r, w, _ := os.Pipe()

log.SetOutput(w)

go func() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    log.Println("Hello, world!")
}()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/HdEs5tbDYDE

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the `io.Reader` is `os.Stderr`, `scanner.Scan()` blocks indefinitely, whereas if I set it to a custom reader like a `*bytes.Buffer`, it returns immediately before the Goroutine has a chance to write to it.

Since the context of this logic is a unit test, I worked around this by using [`assert.Eventually`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Eventually):

```golang
func TestScan(t *testing.T) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
    log.SetOutput(buf)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        log.Println("Hello, world!")
    }()

    assert.Eventually(t, func() bool {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(buf)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "Hello, world!") {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }, 10*time.Second, 100*time.Millisecond)
}
```

This test passes in 1.1 seconds as expected:

```
> go test ./... -v
=== RUN   TestScan
--- PASS: TestScan (1.10s)
PASS
```

(Granted, this is not the most efficient solution as it presumably reads the entire output each time, but it should do the job).